# Cloudera - Sqoop codegen custom ORM class on import

Tags: hadoop, orm, cloudera, sqoop, codegen

I am new to Cloudera environment, I am trying to import data from RDBMS using [Sqoop](http://sqoop.apache.org/) and I need to apply some transformations to data during the import. Specifically I need to encrypt some fields before storing them on the Hadoop DFS. To accomplish this I am trying to use the [codegen](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.0-incubating/SqoopUserGuide.html#id1770798) command, which generates an ORM java class that I can modify.

Let's say I have a table 'products' on MySQL database and I want to import it on HDFS using Sqoop and encrypt the 'brand' field.
First I've run this command:

```
sqoop codegen \ 
--connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/test \
--username username --password password \
--table products
```

This generates the files products.java, products.jar and products.class in the folder /tmp/sqoop-training/compile/fc8868dda33ef703ad126583cf77477f.

Now I've modified the method readFields in products.java like so:

```
// WARNING: This class is AUTO-GENERATED. Modify at your own risk.
//
// Debug information:
// Generated date: Thu Nov 16 06:55:13 PST 2017
// For connector: org.apache.sqoop.manager.MySQLManager
import org.apache.hadoop.io.BytesWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Writable;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.db.DBWritable;
import com.cloudera.sqoop.lib.JdbcWritableBridge;
import com.cloudera.sqoop.lib.DelimiterSet;
import com.cloudera.sqoop.lib.FieldFormatter;
import com.cloudera.sqoop.lib.RecordParser;
import com.cloudera.sqoop.lib.BooleanParser;
import com.cloudera.sqoop.lib.BlobRef;
import com.cloudera.sqoop.lib.ClobRef;
import com.cloudera.sqoop.lib.LargeObjectLoader;
import com.cloudera.sqoop.lib.SqoopRecord;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.io.DataInput;
import java.io.DataOutput;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.CharBuffer;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.Time;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class products extends SqoopRecord  implements DBWritable, Writable {

    // [...]

    public void readFields(ResultSet __dbResults) throws SQLException {
        this.__cur_result_set = __dbResults;
        this.prod_id = JdbcWritableBridge.readInteger(1, __dbResults);
        this.brand = encrypt(JdbcWritableBridge.readString(2, __dbResults));
        this.name = JdbcWritableBridge.readString(3, __dbResults);
        this.price = JdbcWritableBridge.readInteger(4, __dbResults);
        this.cost = JdbcWritableBridge.readInteger(5, __dbResults);
        this.shipping_wt = JdbcWritableBridge.readInteger(6, __dbResults);
    }

    // [...]

}
```

I have two questions: 
**1) How can I recompile the products.java to obtain updated versions of products.class and products.jar?** I've tried with

```
javac products.java
```

but JVM gives 82 errors, it seems it cannot find packages from hadoop and cloudera namespace:

```
error: package org.apache.hadoop.io does not exist
import org.apache.hadoop.io.BytesWritable;
                           ^
products.java:8: error: package org.apache.hadoop.io does not exist
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
                           ^
products.java:9: error: package org.apache.hadoop.io does not exist
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Writable;
                           ^
products.java:10: error: package org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.db does not exist
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.db.DBWritable;
                                      ^
products.java:11: error: package com.cloudera.sqoop.lib does not exist
import com.cloudera.sqoop.lib.JdbcWritableBridge;
                             ^
products.java:12: error: package com.cloudera.sqoop.lib does not exist
import com.cloudera.sqoop.lib.DelimiterSet;
                             ^
products.java:13: error: package com.cloudera.sqoop.lib does not exist
import com.cloudera.sqoop.lib.FieldFormatter;
                             ^
products.java:14: error: package com.cloudera.sqoop.lib does not exist
import com.cloudera.sqoop.lib.RecordParser;
                             ^
products.java:15: error: package com.cloudera.sqoop.lib does not exist
import com.cloudera.sqoop.lib.BooleanParser;
                             ^
products.java:16: error: package com.cloudera.sqoop.lib does not exist
import com.cloudera.sqoop.lib.BlobRef;
                             ^
products.java:17: error: package com.cloudera.sqoop.lib does not exist
import com.cloudera.sqoop.lib.ClobRef;
                             ^
products.java:18: error: package com.cloudera.sqoop.lib does not exist
import com.cloudera.sqoop.lib.LargeObjectLoader;
                             ^
products.java:19: error: package com.cloudera.sqoop.lib does not exist
import com.cloudera.sqoop.lib.SqoopRecord;
```

**2) Once I have successfully compiled products.java, how can I use Sqoop to import data on HDFS using my custom ORM class?**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

On first question:

Add

```
export CLASSPATH=`hadoop classpath`:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/sqoop/lib
```

and then try again.

ps. Generally on architecture, minor comment on "Specifically I need to encrypt some fields before storing them on the Hadoop DFS" - why don't you use HDFS Transparent Encryption? https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/cdh_sg_hdfs_encryption.html You can achieve the same without any coding.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately the folder /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/sqoop does not exists. I can see only /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hue folder. Running command 'hadoop version' on terminal I can see that the CDH version is: cdh5.8.0.

Comment: Do you have sqoop 1 or sqoop 2 installed? Was it installed as a parcel or a package? Did you add a sqoop 1 service through CM?